# How to wait for Flutter's Timer.periodic to cancel?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a function which periodically checks a condition and I want the function to ONLY proceed once the condition is met. This seems like such a basic task, but for some reason I cannot find a good way to solve this.

When I call the function below, I always get 'job not done yet' first and then after three seconds 'job done'. How can I make it proceed to the return statement only after the counter == 3 ?
Sorry if this is such a noob thing to ask. I used Google, I promise, but to no avail.

```
Future<String> delayTest() async {
    var counter = 0;
    await Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      counter++;
      if (counter == 3) {
        print('job done');
        timer.cancel();
      }
    });
   
    return ('job not done yet.');
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wait until timer gets canceled. Something like this:

```
Future<String> delayTest() async {
  var counter = 0;
  const duration = Duration(seconds: 1);
  final timer = Timer.periodic(duration, (timer) {
    counter++;
    print('not done yet');
    if (counter == 3) {
      print('job done');
      timer.cancel();
    }
  });
  while (timer.isActive) {
    // waiting for the same time duration to check if timer is still active after it
    await Future.delayed(duration);
  }
  return 'done';
}
```

Comment: Using a `Completer` would be more efficient (and IMO more straightforward) than polling.  See [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78195089/).

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`Completer`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-async/Completer-class.html).  As explained by [Effective Dart](https://dart.dev/effective-dart/usage#avoid-using-completer-directly), this is the sort of situation where using a `Completer` is appropriate:

> `Completer` is needed for two kinds of low-level code: new asynchronous primitives, and interfacing with asynchronous code that doesn't use futures. Most other code should use async/await or `Future.then()`, because they're clearer and make error handling easier.

```dart
import 'dart:async';

Future<String> delayTest() async {
  var counter = 0;
  var completer = Completer<void>();
  
  Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
    counter++;
    if (counter == 3) {
      print('job done');
      timer.cancel();
      completer.complete();
    }
  });
  
  await completer.future;

  return 'Timer ran to completion.';
}

void main() async {
  print(await delayTest());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to wait 3 seconds
You can use

```
Future<String> delayTest() async {
   await Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 3));

   return ('job not done yet.');
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but that's not quite what I had in mind. I don't want the function to wait 3 seconds, instead I want it to wait until the condition is true (in this example until the counter is three). In the original case I will be checking a network variable repeatedly until it is true and only then proceed with the rest of the function.